# What is wrong with my PHP code

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

My PHP code doesn't seem to be working. I don't get any errors, it just displays a blank page. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("quicktesting") or die(mysql_error());

//Select and order the content from forum_sections in ascending order 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_section ORDER BY ordered ASC LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());

$displayList = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql) or die(mysql_error())) {
    $sectionID = $row["id"];
    $sectionTitle = $row["title"];
     $displayList = '<a href="section.php?id='.$sectionID.'">'.$sectionTitle.'</a><br />';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Forums Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header_bakcground">
            <div id="moreHead">
                <p>Testing Forums</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mainBody">
            <?php echo $displayList; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

PS: I am trying to make a forum website, if you know any good tutorials or techniques please tell me. Also, I'm not very good at JavaScript and am wondering if it's necessary in a good forum website.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: try setting `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script

Comment: You are wrong with your PHP code.

Comment: remove the double quote from this:  `$displayList = '<a href="section.php?id='.$sectionID.'">'`

Comment: *Blank page* typically means a PHP error. Check your error logs.

Comment: Run Internet search on `web forum PHP`.  Download package.  Learn PHP. Develop.

Comment: Dont you need to loop through your while statement in the `mainBody`? It looks like you are resetting `$displayList` each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql) or die(mysql_error())` is bad logic. `while` statements run until their condition returns false, which in this case would by `mysql_fetch_array` returning false; however, since you have `or die(mysql_error())` which will return a non-false value your code is dying right away.

Change to: `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))`

Comment: That worked! But I came across another error, I have 4 rows in my database, do you know why it's only displaying one?

Comment: Replace `$displayList = '` with `$displayList .= '` in your while loop you are not concanating your html that's why it is displaying last row

Answer (score 1):

Try using, you need add `.` concatenation `$displayList`

```
$displayList .= '<a href="section.php?id='.$sectionID.'">'.$sectionTitle.'</a><br />';
```

instead of

```
$displayList = '<a href="section.php?id='.$sectionID.'">'.$sectionTitle.'</a><br />';
```

It should be like:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   $sectionID = $row["id"];
   $sectionTitle = $row["title"];
   $displayList .= '<a href="section.php?id='.$sectionID.'">'.$sectionTitle.'</a><br />';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change "while" to

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $sectionID = $row["id"];
    $sectionTitle = $row["title"];
    $displayList .= '<a href="section.php?id='.$sectionID.'">'.$sectionTitle.'</a><br />';
}
```